# Partial collection counter alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, counter

Rails can render partial collection with counter:

```
= render partial: 'item', collection: @items
```

inside _`item.html`, rails provides iteration counter for the `items`. ([here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html))

```
= item_counter
```

How to make an alias for `item_counter` e.g. `partial_counter`? Or anything that will make it become more DRY? It's quite ineffisient writing `item_counter, product_counter, category_counter, user_counter, ...`. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
= render partial: 'item', collection: @items, as: 'item'
```

**UPDATED:** Alias counter only:
Unfortunately there is no any other Rails' ways to do what you looking for. You have to define new local variable and assign counter value in all partials by hands:

```
<% counter = local_assigns.detect {|var, value| var.match(/_counter\z/)}.last %>

<%= counter %>
```

Comment: the partial should stay `item`, `product`, `category`, etc. The counter that should be aliased. It will be overwhelmed if all partials are aliased with `item`. Another reason, all partials have already implemented, but I forgot adding counter to them.